# How do I wrap this cv.glmnet into a function?

Tags: r, function, survival-analysis

This is the basic code which I need to run quite a number of times given the genes sets I have.

```
x <-as.matrix(pca_matrix1)
y <- Surv(surv_obj1$OS_MONTHS,surv_obj1$Status)



set.seed(02042019) ## for reproducibility    
ix <- sample(1:nrow(x), 0.7*nrow(x)) 
y_tr <- y[ix]
x_tr <- x[ix,]
y_te <- y[-ix]
x_te <- x[-ix,]

#library(glmnet)
cvfit_tr <- cv.glmnet(x_tr,y_tr,family="cox",nfolds = 10, alpha = 1)
plot(cvfit_tr)





co_mat <- as.matrix(coef(cvfit_tr,s="lambda.min"))
co_mat[co_mat[,1]!=0,]



## get predictions x^Tbeta
preds <- predict(cvfit_tr,x_te,s="lambda.min",type="link")
preds
## split into low, medium, high risk groups
#library(ggplot2)
levs <- cut_number(preds,2)
fit <- survfit(y_te~levs)
out <- survdiff(y_te~levs)
out
broom::glance(out)$p.value
```

One of my attempt to create the function

```
lasso_surv <- function(exprs, surv, alpha = 1, nfolds = 10, lambda = NULL, genes = NULL) {
  

  x <- as.matrix(exprs)
  y <- Surv(surv$OS_MONTHS, surv$Status)
  
  cv.fit <- cv.glmnet(x, y, nfolds = nfolds, alpha = alpha, type.measure = "cox")
  
  best.lambda <- cv.fit$lambda.min
  fit <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = alpha, lambda = best.lambda)
  coef <- as.matrix(fit$beta[, drop = FALSE])
  
  lasso.result <- list(cvfit = cv.fit, fit = fit, coef = coef)
  return(lasso.result)
}
```

When i run this i get this error

```
lasso_result <- lasso_surv(as.matrix(x_te), y_te)
Error in surv$OS_MONTHS : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Here I have already created `surv` object

```
y <- Surv(surv_obj1$OS_MONTHS,surv_obj1$Status)
```

I'm sure there is something very basic error in the code which Im not able to figure it out

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated

**UPDATED**

Code suggested by [itIsNaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5895154/itisnaz)

```
lasso_surv <- function(exprs, OS_MONTHS, Status, alpha = 1, nfolds = 10, lambda = NULL, genes = NULL) {
  
  y <- Surv(OS_MONTHS, Status) 
  x <- as.matrix(exprs)     
  cv.fit <- cv.glmnet(x, y, nfolds = nfolds, alpha = alpha, family="cox")     
  best.lambda <- cv.fit$lambda.min   
  fit <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = alpha, lambda = best.lambda)  
  coef <- as.matrix(fit$beta[, drop = FALSE])      
  lasso.result <- list(cvfit = cv.fit, fit = fit, coef = coef)  
  return(lasso.result) 
  
}

resullt <- lasso_surv(x,surv_obj1$OS_MONTHS,surv_obj1$Status)
```

Error

```
Error in Ops.Surv(x, w) : Invalid operation on a survival time
```

I have modified type.measure to family= cox

**UPDATE**
My survival data

```
dput(surv_obj1)
structure(list(OS_MONTHS = c(5.3, 95.5, 25.8, 7.1, 21.5, 43.4, 
7.7, 81.9, 32.6, 44.4, 11.3, 32.3, 99.9, 15.4, 20.5, 6.3, 6.6, 
8.1, 1.2, 19, 11.5, 55.4, 73, 11.2, 10.2, 52.6, 57.3, 4.6, 7.5, 
30.5, 6.3, 45.8, 69, 46.8, 22.6, 95.6, 10.5, 11.8, 28.4, 26.3, 
43.5, 4.5, 52.7, 3.9, 30.6, 61.2, 47.5, 0.6, 45.3, 12.2, 2.4, 
9.3, 8.1, 59.3, 19.2, 26.3, 41.4, 36.9, 0.5, 8.2, 7.4, 36.1, 
1.4, 5.5, 0.3, 88.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 8.4, 4.2, 29.7, 0.8, 67.7, 
18.1, 5.7, 0.1, 5.7, 13.8, 6.6, 48.3, 56.3, 27.1, 24.4, 5.6, 
53.9, 4, 26, 10.2, 34, 35.2, 47, 24.1, 42.1, 76.2, 7, 77.3, 32.7, 
16.4, 9.3, 17, 7.9, 24.8, 0.3, 22.3, 27, 83.5, 34.3, 3.1, 7.5, 
6.6, 5.2, 83.3, 33.5, 16.3, 2.3, 75.8, 42.1, 30, 7.7, 0.7, 20.5, 
1, 1.3, 11, 73.6, 40.3, 1.3, 1.6, 27.4, 1.9, 29.4, 18.5, 59, 
118.1, 8, 2.4, 47.2, 37.1, 26.8, 86.6, 46.5, 27.7, 71.3, 10.7, 
4.6), Status = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 
72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 
85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 
98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 
109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 
120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 
131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 
142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L), class = "data.frame")
```

and expression dummy dataframe matching the survival dimension

```
genes <- paste0("Gene", 1:30)

# Create a matrix with 146 rows and 30 columns
exprs <- matrix(rnorm(146*30), nrow = 146, ncol = 30)

# Set the column names to be the gene names
colnames(exprs) <- genes
```

Comment: ```lasso_surv <- function(exprs, OS_MONTHS, Status, alpha = 1, nfolds = 10, lambda = NULL, genes = NULL) {
  
  y <- Surv(OS_MONTHS, Status)
  x <- as.matrix(exprs)
  
  cv.fit <- cv.glmnet(x, y, nfolds = nfolds, alpha = alpha, type.measure = "cox")
  
  best.lambda <- cv.fit$lambda.min
  fit <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = alpha, lambda = best.lambda)
  coef <- as.matrix(fit$beta[, drop = FALSE])
  
  lasso.result <- list(cvfit = cv.fit, fit = fit, coef = coef)
  return(lasso.result)
}
```

Comment: let me run this

Comment: ok let me know if it does fit your need

Comment: im still running  i get this error , `resullt <- lasso_surv(x,surv_obj1$OS_MONTHS,surv_obj1$Status)
Error in match.arg(type.measure) :
'arg' should be one of “default”, “mse”, “deviance”, “class”, “auc”, “mae”, “C”`

Comment: The error message "Error in match.arg(type.measure) : 'arg' should be one of “default”, “mse”, “deviance”, “class”, “auc”, “mae”, “C”" suggests that the type.measure argument in the cv.glmnet() function call is invalid.

The type.measure argument specifies the type of measure used in cross-validation to select the best value of the regularization parameter lambda. The default value is "deviance" for Cox proportional hazards models, but you can set it to "mse" or "mae" for mean squared error or mean absolute error, respectively. how you call the functionn

Comment: @itIsNaz i get this error `Error in Ops.Surv(x, w) : Invalid operation on a survival time` after running your updated code

Comment: how you call the function ?

Comment: This is how ` lasso_surv(x,surv_obj1$OS_MONTHS,surv_obj1$Status)`

Comment: @itIsNaz do you need some data to reproduce it? if yes let me know I can put it in pastebin

Comment: Ok i gonna give you some debug steps please check them: 
- The Surv object may not have been created correctly. Double-check that the input arguments to the Surv function are valid.
- You may be trying to perform an invalid operation on the Surv object, such as arithmetic operations or indexing. The Surv object is a special type of object in R and cannot be treated like a regular numeric or character vector.
- The Surv object may not be compatible with the function you're using it in. Some functions in R may not be designed to work with Surv objects.

Comment: yes if you can give some data

Comment: okay wait creating

Comment: @itIsNaz may be now you can add them as answer I have updated it since that would be clear to read

Comment: I don't understand , i still waiting for your data example haha ; if i understood , your problem is solved ?

Comment: I have added the data please see the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(glmnet)
library(survival)

# Function for Lasso regularization on survival data
lasso_surv <- function(exprs, OS_MONTHS, Status, alpha = 1, nfolds = 10, lambda = NULL, genes = NULL) {
  
  y <- Surv(OS_MONTHS, Status) 
  x <- as.matrix(exprs)     
  cv.fit <- cv.glmnet(x, y, nfolds = nfolds, alpha = alpha, family="cox")     
  best.lambda <- cv.fit$lambda.min   
  fit <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = alpha, lambda = best.lambda, family = "cox")  
  coef <- as.matrix(fit$beta[, drop = FALSE])      
  lasso.result <- list(cvfit = cv.fit, fit = fit, coef = coef)  
  return(lasso.result) 
  
}

# Generate simulated survival data
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
p <- 50
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*p), n, p)
beta <- c(runif(20, 0.5, 1), rep(0, p-20))
colnames(x) <- paste0("gene", 1:p)
y <- c(rep(1, 50), rep(0, 50))
t <- rexp(n, exp(x %*% beta))

# Create survival object
surv_obj1 <- data.frame(OS_MONTHS = t, Status = y)

# Run lasso_surv on survival object
res <- lasso_surv(x, surv_obj1$OS_MONTHS, surv_obj1$Status, nfolds = 10, alpha = 1)

print(res)
```

[image]

Comment: what was the error earlier? with surv object?

Comment: the object was not good , this was what i suggest it for you in my previous comments, i do wish thqt it helps

Comment: okay but the same object when I used to run sequentially like normal command I could get output but thank a lot for fixing this...